# magento redirect all https urls to www excluding checkout page

Tags: .htaccess, magento

I need to redirect all pages with https:

- https://shop.test.com/
- https://shop.test.com/several_parameters

To http://www.test.com.

But we should not redirect a page like

- https://shop.test.com/checkout/onepage

Comment: Please post the code

Comment: you can do it by changing .htaccess file. Here is a link to the apache wiki http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteHTTPToHTTPS

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there are certain URLs that you want to allow as https on shop.test.com.  For each of these rules, add a RewriteCond like the following (replacing {URL HERE} with the URL you want to allow):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^{URL HERE}
```

Here is the entirety of the solution to deal with the cases that you specified above:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^shop.test.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/checkout/onepage
RewriteRule .* http://www.test.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

## Caution!

It's worth noting that if you don't whitelist a URL that is listed as secure by Magento that you will create an infinite redirect loop.  To help make sure that you whitelist every possible secure URL, you can grep the codebase for `<secure_url>` and whitelist each of those endpoints.

Comment: thank you for the reply. i have tried your script but it is is still redirecting to test.com when I browse page https://shop.test.com/checkout/onepage/  . With this url, it shouldn't redirect to test.com

Comment: What are your secure and insecure URLs in Magento?

Comment: (https:// ) https://shop.test.com/ is secured url and (http://)shop.test.com/ is insecure url. Please remove braces..its not showing http/https

Comment: You need to set www.Test.com as insecure URL

Comment: So when your script is moved to live where insecured url also has www, will work, right?